# Simultaneous fetch in express

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

I want to call multiple external APIs in one of my express routes, but fetch uses promises.

Would one set a flag to see if all requests are complete before sending the result back to the requester?

Comment: one would use `Promise.all` if you want to send all the requests at once and wait for all to complete ... or `Promise.allSettled` - if that is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array containing all the Promises pending for the requests and wait till `Promise.all` resolves:

```
const allRequests = [....] 

await Promise.all(allRequests);

// handle other tasks and return response to the requester
```

Comment: sure, but this example will not be able to send `the result back to the requester` - since you basically ignore the result

Comment: Yeah I mean it should do other things after that and return whatever it wants. Editing right now